# docker-compose networking multiple apps with same service name

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

Problem:

When having two docker-compose files / projects with the same services, under the same network, when you spin up t he second compose project, the DNS name for the service gets overwritten.

eg:

App 1

```
version: "3.1"
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: monolith-db
    networks:
      - my-network-name

  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: monolith-webserver
    networks:
      - my-network-name

  phpfpm:
    container_name: monolith-phpfpm
    networks:
      - my-network-name
networks:
  my-network-name:
    external: true
```

App 2

```
version: "3.1"
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: ms-auth-db
    networks:
      - my-network-name

  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: ms-auth-webserver
    networks:
      - my-network-name

  phpfpm:
    container_name: ms-auth-phpfpm
    networks:
      - my-network-name
networks:
  my-network-name:
    external: true
```

If you start App 1, the services inside can connect to their declared services by service name as hostname, for example, in my config I have `database-host: db`
However, when I do `docker-compose -p ms-auth --env-file .env -f infra/local/docker-compose.yml up -d` then `db` hostname now points to App 2's db service.

Comment: You have the two files set up to share a network.  Does one `phpfpm` container need to call the other `webserver`?  Or are both Compose setups running behind a reverse proxy somewhere, and they don't directly call each other?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use the `container_name` as hostname

e.g. instead of connecting to `db`, configure App 1' config files to use the hostname `monolith-db`, and for pointing from App 1 to App 2, also use container name as hostname, e.g. `ms-auth-host: ms-auth-webserver`

Comment: You can also set a manual alias for services: `service: service_name: networks: my-network-name: aliases: - alias_name` if container_name does not suit your needs. You can check the aliases with `docker inspect`.